# List WordPress Tags starting for letter A

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

I have a WordPress blog and want only to show all the tags that start with letter A. I mean all the tags listed in the full website. I need a massive list of all the tags that begin with letter A that are contained in the full blog.

All the other tags (beginning for B, C etc..) will not be shown.

The following code lists tags that contain letter "a", but I need tags that **begin** with letter "a".

```
<ul class="index-p clearfix">
<h3>A</h3>
<?php
$tags = get_tags( array('name__like' => "a", 'order' => 'ASC') );
foreach ( (array) $tags as $tag ) { ?>
<li>
<a href="<?php echo get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ) ?>">

<span class="info">
<span class="name"><?php echo $tag->name ?></span>
</span>
</a>
</li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Since WordPress 3.7 `name__like` doesn't match terms that begin with the string anymore. I'm looking for a workaround.

Comment: I don't know Wordpress, but a php hack would be to filter, i.e. `if(strpos($tag->name,'a') !== false) { ....show the tag ... }`

Comment: You can try to use the search parameter with wildcard ('%'). For example: $tags = get_tags( array('search' => "a%", 'order' => 'ASC') ). You can also try: $tags = get_tags( array('name__like' => "a%", 'order' => 'ASC') );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for first character of tag name and ignore if first character is not the one you want as below:

```
    <ul class="index-p clearfix">
<h3>A</h3>
<?php
$tags = get_tags( array('name__like' => "a", 'order' => 'ASC') );
foreach ( (array) $tags as $tag ) {
if(strtolower(substr($tag->name,0,1)) !="a"){
    continue;
    }?>
<li>
<a href="<?php echo get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ) ?>">
<span class="info">
<span class="name"><?php echo $tag->name ?></span>
</span>
</a>
</li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

NOTE: Replace "a" with any letter you want.